# jQuery Filter on input name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm creating a dialog box that shows a list of hotel chains. My dialog box is creating fine

```
<div id="HotelDialog" class="popup ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
 <div class="popup-hotel">
  <div class="checkbox">
   <input id="ChainBR" type="checkbox" name="HotelChainBR" value="BR" checked="checked" onclick="filterChain();">
   <label for="ChainBR">BR Hotel</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
   <input id="ChainBW" type="checkbox" name="HotelChainBW" value="BW" checked="checked" onclick="filterChain();">
   <label for="ChainBW">BW Hotel</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
   <input id="ChainCI" type="checkbox" name="HotelChainCI" value="CI" checked="checked" onclick="filterChain();">
   <label for="ChainCI">CI Hotel</label>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My ultimate goal is users will click on each hotel and if they uncheck the box have a div with a data-chain value equal to the checkbox value disappear. I've gotten to the point where I'm trying to output the check box values into the console each time one is checked/unchecked, but it only outputs BR each time. What am I doing wrong in my selector statement?

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var hotelchains = [['BR'],['BW'],['CI']]; 

function filterChain() {
 for (loopcnt = 0; loopcnt <= (hotelchains.length-1); loopcnt++) {
  var singlechain = $('input[name^="HotelChain"]').val();
  console.log(singlechain);
 };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `val` only returns the value of the first selected element and you are selecting same elements in each iteration, You can use `eq` or `each` method:

```
$('input[name^="HotelChain"]').each(function(){
    var val = this.value;
    console.log(val)
})
```

or:

```
var hotelchains = ['BR','BW','CI']; 
var $input = $('input[name^="HotelChain"]');

function filterChain() {
   for (var i = 0; i < hotelchains.length ; i++) {
      var singlechain = $input.filter('[name="HotelChain'+hotelchains[i]+'"]').val();
      console.log(singlechain);
   };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name^="HotelChain"]').val();
```

This will only output the first value found by the selector..

That's the reason you always see **BR**

Also check your array .. It should be like

```
var hotelchains = ['BR','BW','CI'];
```

Try this

```
var hotelchains = ['BR','BW','CI']; 

function filterChain() {
 for (loopcnt = 0; loopcnt <= (hotelchains.length-1); loopcnt++) {
  var singlechain = $('input[name="HotelChain' + hotelchains[loopcnt] + '"]').val();
  console.log(singlechain);
 };​
```

Comment: i've fixed my array, I accepted the other answer for simplicity although this works just as well